# Can I increase the player limit in my world?

Tags: android, terraria-mobile

I have 5 friends, and we all want to play together, but there can only be 4 other players in my world. Is there a way to remove the player limit so that we can all be in the same world?

Comment: there is a hardcoded limit of 5 characters

Comment: My world is already hardcore :D

Answer (score -1):

Not right now.

In the Terraria Mobile version, both IOS and Android versions only support 4 players, so your friends can't play with each other unless they take turns, which I highly discourage.

The only thing you can do is wait for the developers to do something about it. I believe you can send them an email to complain or suggest enabling more players, but it could still take a while.